# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Estou tendo que fazer um SELECT no JPA que contenha um ORDER BY selecionando de uma outra tabela.

Pequena representação das tabelas:
[image: Pequena Representação das tabelas]

Quando fiz pelo SQL foi normal, mas ao transformar em JPA, não deu certo, e caso eu tire o JPA ele funciona normalmente.

> 2018-03-28 16:36:20 ERROR stderr     -
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST
>   node: query [SELECT v.fornecedor FROM
>   br.com.souvizinho.modelo.VinculoCategoriaFornecedor v WHERE
>   v.categoria IN  ( SELECT o.categoria FROM
>   br.com.souvizinho.modelo.OrcamentoCategoria o WHERE o.usercad =
>   :usercad  AND o.condominio = :condominio AND o.orcamento = 1 AND
>   o.ativo = 1)  AND v.ativo = 1 GROUP BY v.fornecedor ORDER BY  ( SELECT
>   AVG(n.nota) FROM br.com.souvizinho.modelo.AvaliacaoFornecedor n WHERE
>   n.fornecedor = v.fornecedor ) DESC]

**SQL:**

```
SELECT vinculocat11.fornecedor
FROM   tbvinculocategoriafornecedor vinculocat11
       CROSS JOIN tbfornecedor fornecedor12
WHERE  vinculocat11.fornecedor = fornecedor12.nrseq
       AND ( vinculocat11.categoria IN (SELECT orcamentoc13.categoria
                                        FROM   tborcamentocategoria orcamentoc13
                                               CROSS JOIN tbcategoriafornecedor
                                                          categoriaf14
                                        WHERE  orcamentoc13.categoria =
                                               categoriaf14.nrseq
                                               AND orcamentoc13.usercad = 56
                                               AND orcamentoc13.condominio = 2
                                               AND orcamentoc13.orcamento = 1
                                               AND orcamentoc13.ativo = 1) )
       AND vinculocat11.ativo = 1
GROUP  BY vinculocat11.fornecedor
ORDER  BY (SELECT Avg(n.nota)
           FROM   tbavaliacaofornecedor AS n
           WHERE  n.fornecedor = vinculocat11.fornecedor) DESC
```

**JPA:**

```
fornecedores = this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT v.fornecedor FROM VinculoCategoriaFornecedor v WHERE v.categoria IN "
                    + " ( SELECT o.categoria FROM OrcamentoCategoria o WHERE o.usercad = :usercad "
                    + " AND o.condominio = :condominio AND o.orcamento = 1 AND o.ativo = 1) "
                    + " AND v.ativo = 1 GROUP BY v.fornecedor ORDER BY "
                    + " ( SELECT AVG(n.nota) FROM AvaliacaoFornecedor n WHERE n.fornecedor = v.fornecedor ) DESC")
                    .setParameter("usercad", usercad).setParameter("condominio", condominio).getResultList();
```

Comment: Você poderia coloca a estrutura de dados do seu BD. Somente com os métodos CREATE

Comment: Olá tenta dar nome aos parametros diferente das colunas, ou defina um prefixo/sufixo